# Error: Unable to get the AutoFilter property of the Range class

Tags: excel, vsto, autofilter

In the following code, I receive the above-named error, *only on the second call to AutoFilter()*.

```
string FilterValue1 = tbSysCat1.Text.FilterDoesNotContain();
string FilterValue2 = tbSysCat2.Text.FilterDoesNotContain();
string FilterValue3 = tbSysCat3.Text.FilterDoesNotContain();

string[] SysCat = new string[6];    // EDIT: originally tried object[]; still got error
SysCat[0] = FilterValue1;
SysCat[1] = FilterValue1.ToUpper();
SysCat[2] = FilterValue2;
SysCat[3] = FilterValue2.ToUpper();
SysCat[4] = FilterValue3;
SysCat[5] = FilterValue3.ToUpper();

VApplication.ActiveSheet.Range[VWorkingRange].AutoFilter(9, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true);
VApplication.ActiveSheet.Range[VWorkingRange].AutoFilter(9, SysCat, MSExcel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues, Missing.Value, true);
```

*Note: FilterDoesNotContain() is an extension method to add the Excel-specific wildcards for "does not contain".*

From my other research, the error indicates that AutoFilter could not be associated with the Range object at runtime (since it is a dynamic type). However, it was associated just fine in the first call. **That's the baffling part.**

The first call is there to clear the filter for column 9.

Environment: VSTO in VS2010 using .NET 4.0 **(EDIT: MS Excel 2007 Pro)**

Appreciate your help!

Comment: AutoFilter is natively built to work with two criteria. To use multiple criteria, I used the method suggested in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsto/thread/45d43ed9-cbfd-4843-a8d6-2918705ec992 by Cindy Meister. I've successfully used the method in other sections of my project. It only fails in this particular code segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In posting my question, I may have omitted some information that was crucial to pinpointing the cause of the error. I failed to mention that my data was being tested for **"does not contain"** criteria.

After more research and stumbling [on this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lv/isvvba/thread/b9befef0-cb6b-43be-8644-af53db78a515), I learned that the operator xlFilterValues does not work with filter criteria "does not contain."

It only works with exact matches of cell values. Maybe this is obvious to some of you, it was not to me. I expected that one can pass filter values into the array containing the Excel special character to indicate "does not contain" (for ex, "<>*data*")

In case it wasn't clear above, the error was caused by me passing "<>*data*" in an array using xlFilterValues operator.

The solution:
I created a separate function to manually harvest all the column data that did not contain my criteria fields. The function returned an array which contained ***the data I wanted to keep***. Then, I passed this array into AutoFilter() as normal using the xlFilterValues operator and all was well. It feels hacky, but after a day of researching this problem, I'm okay with this solution.

**Thanks shahkalpesh for your time and effort in helping me.** Hopefully, this answer helps you down the road too.

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry, I don't have Excel to try this out.
However, change the following line

`VApplication.ActiveSheet.Range[VWorkingRange].AutoFilter(9, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true);`

to

`VApplication.ActiveSheet.Range[VWorkingRange].AutoFilter(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);`

OR

`VApplication.ActiveSheet.Range[VWorkingRange].AutoFilter();`

This is the way to clear the `AutoFilter`.
i.e. When you click on auto filter button, all columns get the filter and not a specific one.
As a result, you will have to clear the auto filter (by not telling it the column).

EDIT: Just in case it helps, generate the macro of what you are wanting to do in VBA. If it works, translate it to c#.

EDIT: To add multiple criteria, you can get reference to `ActiveSheet.AutoFilter` property (once auto filter is in effect). To this property, you can further criterias.

Take a look at this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb255835%28v=office.12%29.aspx), specifically the `Filters` collection  <strike>to which you can add criterias using `Filters.Add`.</strike>

Comment: Thanks for the help. The thing is, there are multiple columns involved. This code is in a function that filters column 9. I do use your suggested AutoFilter() call to clear all the columns before all the other function calls for the other columns.

Comment: I tried your macro suggestion. I'm only able to enter two criteria, so the macro code uses the xlAnd operator, instead of the xlFilterValues operator. Elsewhere, in other functions, I use similar code for two criteria and that works just fine. This particular case uses 6 criteria. (I have another case where I filter with 4 criteria and use the same sequence of calling AutoFilter twice as above--and of course, that works fine)

Comment: I looked at your suggested MSDN page. Filters is read-only. The Filters collection only shows what has already been added, through I assume, the "normal" means of passing the criteria into the AutoFilter() call.

Comment: I am sorry I couldn't help much. I hope you did get the question answered using the link added by you in the comment.